# PostgreSQL deprecated configuration parameters

Tags: database, postgresql, configuration, deprecated

I am upgrading my PostgreSQL from 9.2.24 to 10.4. During the upgrade I found that some of the configuration parameter have been deprecated. Its very hard for me to figure out what parameters my all clients are using. So can anybody help me to figure out a comprehensive list of all configuration parameters which PostgreSQL has deprecated?

I found this [link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deprecated_Features#Configuration_parameters) but am not sure whether this list is complete or not, or if I should trust this or not. I have to tackle all the parameters during my product upgrade, otherwise my product upgrade will fail in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to come up with this list by yourself. Create new test clusters in both versions and go through `postgresql.conf` line by line.

It helps a lot that the file is grouped in sections, so you can compare section by section.

For each removed and for each new parameter, read up about them in the fine manual. Also consult the release notes of the major releases in between, which will give you valuable guidance how to translate the settings.

It may take a few hours, but it is well invested time, because afterwards you will know more about your database.

Comment: Accepting your answer as their seems no other way.